# Extract column of numbers from website with other numbers

Tags: regex

There is this website (http://dgpred.cbr.su.se/index.php?p=TMpred) that is used by biochemists/bioinformatics. After entering a protein sequence, you get something like this:

http://dgpred.cbr.su.se/analyze.php?with_length=on&seq=RGFTPLQWECVMASDFGHH

Some data at the top and bottom, and in the middle are 4 columns, where the 4th is the data we want. I want to take these numbers from the 4th column (for a lot of protein sequences) and put in Excel.

My current workflow (Mac OS X) is to copy everything to TextEdit in a rich-text document, alt+drag around the numbers (so that only the numbers from the 4th column are selected), and then do my AppleScript:

```
do shell script "pbpaste | sed 's/[^0-9.-]//g' | pbcopy"
do shell script "pbpaste | sed '/^$/d' | pbcopy"
```

I'm a mere beginner at regex, but this successfully leaves me with a nice list of numbers separated by linebreaks, ready to be pasted into excel.

What would be REALLY sweet is to ditch the TextEdit step and just have the regex take the numbers directly from the website. However, this is beyond my level. Could anyone help me with this? I.e., to only select the numbers from the 4th column

Comment: So you want to extract the `Delta G aa(i) app` column, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copy this data I  get this result:

```
R   1   -9.00           
       +0.03
G   2   -8.00           
       +0.36
F   3   -7.00       
-0.26
```

3 columns on every odd line, starting with a `[A-Z]`, then the data you want on the subsequent line.

the numbers you want have two forms:

```
^\t {3}([-+][0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})$  //for the red numbers
```

and:

```
^([-+][0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}) {3}\t$   //the green numbers
```

You can extract both types like this:

```
^(\t {3})?([-+][0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})( {3}\t)?$
```

The second capture group, `([-+][0-9]+.[0-9]{2})` is the content you are after:

```
s/^(\t {3})?([-+][0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})( {3}\t)?$/$2/g
```

Instead of Applescript, consider BBEdit or [Textwrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/index.html), which you may find easier to use.

Put this in the search field:

```
\r[A-Z].*\r(\t {3})?([-+][0-9]+.[0-9]{2})( {3}\t)?$
```

and this in the replace:

\r\2

select "replace all"

---

how it works

```
 \r        //  carriage return
 [A-Z]     //  any character from A to Z (the lines you DON't want all start with a letter)
 .         // any character
 *         // any number of times
 \r        // carriage return   
           // that deals with the lines you DON't want to keep
 (         // grouping
 \t        // tab character
  {3}      // space character repeated 3 times
 )         // close grouping
 ?         // zero or one occurences of the previous grouping
 (         // grouping (this is the bit you are after)
 [+-]      // character class - one of any of the [enclosed characters]
 [0-9]     // one of any of 0-9
 +         // repeated one or  more times
 \.        // full stop (escaped as it has special meaning in regext)
 [0-9]{2}  // exactly two occurences of any of 0-9
 )         // close capture parens (end of the group you are after)
 ( {3}\t)? // 3 spaces followed by a tab, occurring 0 or 1 time.
 $         // end of line  (in BBEdit/textwrangler you often use \r)
```

*important* detail in BBE/TW, the captured groups are referred to as \1,\2,\3, not $1,$2,$3…

Comment: Wow you're good at this. Unfortunaly, I am not. May I ask how you ran this? I tried to make an applescript (the only way I know to run regex on text in clipboard) `do shell script "pbpaste | sed 's/^(\t {3})?([-+][0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})( {3}\t)?$/$2/g' | pbcopy"` but it gave me an syntax error

Comment: I don't know about applescript - it will run in perl or in the search field in BBEdit. You might like the cut-down version of BBEdit, [Textwrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/index.html) - I think it is free. It will do grep searching and search across file batches.

Comment: @user1461829, see my updated answer with precise instructions for use with BBEdit/Textwrangler

Comment: Huge thanks. Applescript would let me go directly from the web browser to Excel without putting the text in a text edit in between. But yea, a lot of times I have problems getting them to run. I tried TextWrangler and I really like it. And your code works perfect. I get some empty lines with your code, but I just made a "\r \r" to "\r" replace that fixed it. I then started recording in TextWrangler, ran both find and replace, and now I get perfect output

Comment: @user1461829 Glad it worked. Sorry I thought you had some manual steps ("copy everything to TextEdit..."). Anyway as the solution worked can you accept the answer (click on the tick) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that browsers copy tables differently. When I want to copy table data from a web page, I tend to try IE/Chrome/Opera browsers because -- on Windows, at least -- I can simply paste the copied table directly into Excel with all the columns preserved. Firefox, on the other hand, tends to mess the table up.

Copying the table in question using Opera and pasting into Excel from cell A1, I get all the green figures in column F and the red in column H. I then type the following formula in a column to the right of row 1 and drag the cell's corner down to duplicate for subsequent rows:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(F1), ISBLANK(H1)), "", IF(ISBLANK(F1), H1, F1))
```

Now in this new column I see the data. I can paste a new table on top of the original data and the formula to the right recalculates. (Actual columns may be different for other browsers).

I admit it's not a completely automated solution but I find this method to be fast and useful in so many situations that I figured it was worth sharing. And the motto: if at first your browser of choice doesn't do the right thing, try another one!

Comment: Really appreciate that formula. In this situation it's not the ideal solution for me, but I have lots of similar situations where this formula will suit me perfect. Thanks!